# getting No route matches [POST] "/login/log_in"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parse-platform

im using `gem parse-ruby-client` and im trying to create a login. and when the login is successful then i want to go to a welcome#index

here is my login_controller.rb

```
class LoginController < ApplicationController
  def index

  end
  def log_in
    @user = Parse::User.authenticate(params[:user][:username], params[:user][:password])
  end
end
```

index.html.erb

```
<div class="Log_in_Form">
  <h4><center>Log in with your existing "app_name" account</center></h4>
  <%= form_for(:user, :url => {:controller => 'login', :action => 'log_in'}) do |f| %>
    <center><p> Username:</br> <%= f.text_field :username%> </p></center>
    <center><p> Password:</br> <%= f.password_field :password%></p></center>
    <center><h4><%= f.submit :Login %></h4></center>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'welcome/index'

  root 'login#index'  

  get 'login/log_in' => 'login#log_in'
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to have an post route or your login. change your routes to this one (if you need the get route also)

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'welcome/index'

  root 'login#index'  

  get 'login/log_in' => 'login#log_in'
  post 'login/log_in' => 'login#log_in'
end
```

or change

```
get 'login/log_in' => 'login#log_in'
```

to

```
match 'login/log_in' => 'login#log_in', via: [:get, :post]
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the response, i implemented this https://gist.github.com/anonymous/42ad9dedb817a1d3c8d5 and im getting this in return........`Missing template login/log_in, application/log_in with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in: * "/Users/FarhanSyed/rails/parselogin/app/views"`

Comment: You need to create a file called log_in.html.erb in app/views/login and fill it with text you want

Comment: do i put it into views? under the login view?